# Error when importing kerastuner : It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly

Tags: python, keras, keras-tuner

I try to import Kerastuner but it shows

```
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.
```

Then I run `python setup.py install`
It says no file named setup.py
I have scikit-learn installed and kerastuner as well. I am stuck here any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1):

So try using upgrading python version to 3.9.1 64-bit and then try to install using pip install scikit-learn. I have tried and it worked for me...

[image]

This is how it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but this does not answer my question

Comment: can you elaborate me with the error coming now?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Anaconda...

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Comment: I ve used pip equivalent `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: It's not equivalent. You should use the Anaconda channel when you can